# How to access a protected method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, protected, access-modifiers, awesomium

I would like to know how to access a protected method.

I have a WebBrowser Control (Awesomium) which has many protected methods.

I created a Tabbed Browser with this WebControl in a WinForm.

Now I can't use ie `InjectKeyboard`-method cause it's protected.

This is the method:

```
//     Injects a keyboard event.
//
// Parameter:
//   keyEvent:
//     The keyboard event to inject. You'll need to initialize the members of the
//     passed Awesomium.Core.WebKeyboardEvent, yourself.
//
// Note:
//      Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl handles this internally. Inheritors do
//     not need to call this method unless they implement custom logic.  This method
//     bypasses settings of the Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl.InputController.
//      For performance reasons, no validity check is performed when calling protected
//     members.  Inheritors should perform any such checks (see Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl.IsLive),
//     before calling these members.

protected void InjectKeyboardEvent(WebKeyboardEvent keyEvent);
```

While in the API Link is [HERE](http://www.awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/html/d8fef50b-0f4f-ee6f-fc8b-8480b611d667.htm)

Why did they protect this method and how can I use it?

Comment: A function is usually marked as protected because it can alter the state of the object or change the behaviour of the object in such a way that the original coder might not want external callers to be able to do. However, it might be perfectly acceptable for derived classes to do this - hence the usage. In this instance, as the comment mentions, overriding or bypassing this method will change the behaviour of the class with respect to input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i understood why the protected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit from this class and expose the method if you need to (as proposed by the comment above the method).

Comment: So i should create a new Class that inherit WebControl Class and expose Only that method?

Comment: Yes, you should inherit from `Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl`. But maybe you can do what you want in this inherited class and don't need to expose the method as `private/protected` isn't annotated for fun but encapsulates internal behaviour.

Comment: Just to understand(i'm not a Guru Programmer). It this the corret  way to inherit? class WebControlExtend : WebControl
    {
        public void TempInject(WebKeyboardEvent events)
        {
             this.InjectKeyboardEvent(events);
        }
    }

Comment: i tried to use extends instead : but seems how it doesnt exist this keywords. Another thing if u have a spare time , how could use Events in this way? protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e); this one i tried to use public override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) but doesnt work. Says that i havent nothing to Override ofc.

Comment: ouch sorry it's C# and not Java, of course it's `:`. You don't override events, you can attach your handler. What do you want to do with these events?